# How to use mongoose to create a student that's managed by a parent

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, model

## Edit #2: Working code

This does what I want it to do now:

```
// route
app.post("/users/:id/createStudent", function(req, res){
        Student.create(function(err){
                if(err){
                        console.log(err)
                        res.redirect("/")
                } else {
                        const newStudent = new Student({
                                firstName: req.body.firstName,
                                lastName: req.body.lastName,
                                age: req.body.age,
                                instrument: req.body.instrument,
                        });
                        newStudent.save()
                        .then(() => Parent.findById(req.params.id))
                        .then((parent) => {
                                parent.students.push(newStudent);
                                return parent.save();
                        });                 
                        req.flash("success", "Successfully Created Student");
                        res.redirect("/users/:id");
                }
        })
});


 // parent model
    const   mongoose = require("mongoose"),
        Schema = mongoose.Schema,
        passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");


const ParentSchema= new Schema({
    username: String,
    lastName: String,
    email: String,
    password: String,
    students: [],
});

ParentSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

const Parent = mongoose.model("parent", ParentSchema);

module.exports = Parent;
```

Brand new developer here. I'm trying to build an app where a parent user can create a student user and a teacher user can assign said student weekly tasks. I'm having trouble with the create student route. I'm not sure how to get the student object to store the parent's id properly. I've been trying to find a solution for a few days now and can't seem to find anything that deals with this specifically and the docs haven't helped either. I hope I'm just missing something and one of you kind folks can at least point me in the right direction.

Here's my code:

```
//parent model 
const mongoose = require("mongoose"),
        passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");


const parentSchema= new mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    lastName: String,
    email: String,
    password: String,
    student: {
        id: {
           type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
           ref: "Student"
        },
        username: String,
    }
});

parentSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

module.exports = mongoose.model("Parent", parentSchema);

// student model
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const studentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   firstName: String,
   lastName: String,
    age: String,
   instrument: String,
   parent: {
            id: {
               type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
               ref: "Parent"
            },
            username: String
         },
});
 
module.exports = mongoose.model("Student", studentSchema);

// create student route
app.post("/users/:id/createStudent", function(req, res){
    const newStudent = new Student({
            firstName: req.body.firstName,
            lastName: req.body.lastName, 
            age: req.body.age,
            instrument: req.body.instrument,
            parent: {
                    _id: {
                       type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                       ref: "Parent"
                    },
                    username: String
                 },
    });
    Parent.findById(req.params.id, function(err, foundParent){
    if(err){
        req.flash("error", "Something went wrong");
        console.log(err);
        res.redirect("/users/:id");
    } else {
                    const parent = foundParent
        Student.create(newStudent, parent, function(err, student){
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                student.parent.id = req.parent._id;
                student.parent.username = req.parent.username;
                student.save();
                parent.student.push(newStudent);
                parent.save();
                req.flash("success", "Successfully Created Comment");
                res.redirect("/users/" + parent._id);
            }
        })
    }
    });
});
```

In the mongo shell, `db.students.find()` puts out this as my student object after I fill out the form:

```
 db.students.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f0b33facd6fa70355f14774"), "firstName" : "Johnny", "lastName" : "Apple", "age" : "2014-03-04", "instrument" : "drums", "parent" : { "username" : "function String() { [native code] }" }, "__v" : 0 }
```

Sorry for the long code. I've just been trying so many things that it's added up to what you see here. Thanks for any advice you might give and for reading this far.

## Edit

Updated code:

```
app.post("/users/:id/createStudent", function(req, res){
       
        Parent.findById(req.params.id, function(err, foundParent){
          
        if(err){
            req.flash("error", "Something went wrong");
            console.log(err);
            res.redirect("/users/:id");
        } else {
                        const newStudent = new Student({
                                firstName: req.body.firstName,
                                lastName: req.body.lastName, 
                                age: req.body.age,
                                instrument: req.body.instrument,
                                parent:   {
                                        id: foundParent,
                                        username: foundParent.username
                                     },
                        });
            Student.create(newStudent, foundParent, function(err, student){
                if(err){
                                        console.log(err);
                } else {
                    student.parent._id = foundParent._id;
                    student.parent.username = foundParent.username;
                    student.save();
                    foundParent.student.push(newStudent);
                    foundParent.save();
                    req.flash("success", "Successfully Created Student");
                    res.redirect("/users/" + foundParent._id);
                }
            })
        }
        });
});
```

So the new error this is producing is `DocumentNotFoundError: No document found for query "{ _id: 5f0a7026e330500413ee599a }" on model "Student"` which I assume is because I don't have populate in there. I'm just not sure where the populate option would fit in?

Answer (score 0):

`mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId` is a type not a value.

Try using `mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId(req.parent.id)`

**Edit**

Another option to try:
Move the `const newStudent =` block inside the `else` block of the `findById` callback.
Inside the `new Student(` constructor, use

```
parent: {
   id: foundParent,
   username: foundParent.username
}
```

Because of the schema definition, when you save the document, mongoose should store a DBRef in the student collection, which can then be reconstituted with populate.

Comment: Are you saying to replace that within the student model? Or within the route?

Comment: Where you are creating a new student, you are setting the parent.id to the _type_, which is then passed to the mongod as code.  I suspect you intended to put the parent's actual object Id there.

Comment: Yeah that's the goal. I added '(req.parent.id)' to that line and now I'm getting a cannot read property of undefined error.  It looks like parent isn't defined and I'm not sure how to fix that.

Comment: Does the next call `Parent.findById(req.params.id ...` work?

Comment: Yes, console.log(foundParent) gets the parent object. It seems to be getting caught up on when I look for that parent object within the newStudent variable. I think I may have things out of order in the route, but I'm not sure how to refactor them so that everything is called correctly.

Comment: Perhaps mongoose doesn't like you trying to assign the internal values of the DBRef.  I edited the answer with another way to get the values into the student document.

Comment: Interesting... Last question is where does populate go?